# How to find out what size array fits in stack memory?

Tags: c++

It is my impression that when doing this

```
void stuff() {
    int arr[1000];
    //do some stuff
}
```

Then the array could be allocated either in heap or stack memory depending on its size and the limits of the CPU.

I'm optimizing a script that bruteforce tests some calculations and since the estimated time is currently several weeks, I'd like to get that down as much as possible, getting as much sample data as possible fitted in the stack would help I think.

Is there a way to find out how big of an array I can declare?

Comment: In your example, it's always allocated on the stack. That may cause the stack to grow (or overflow), of course (which may in turn result in less heap space), but it's still on the stack. The maximum stack size is completely dependent on your platform -- what is your platform? (Windows x86-64?)

Comment: "getting as much sample data as possible fitted in the stack would help I think" Why do you think that? When it comes down to optimizing bruteforce calculations, the first stop is to stop being so bruteforce-y and start being more clever-y.

Comment: @Cameron yes, Windows x86-64

Comment: No, stack is not likely to help with your bruteforce, unless your current bruteforce is bruforcing malloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack on a typical modern machine varies, but is usually around/less than 5 MB. On embedded platforms in might be a lot less. Some platforms allow to specify a hint for the stack size of a created thread, but often those are only hints and are not strictly followed.

Also, how big object you put on the stack depends on the current stack depth, you could be in the beginning of the stack or near its end. You cannot really tell in advance, I mean at coding time, which is when and where the size of stack arrays is specified. You could assume you will be in the beginning of the stack in the case of a trivial example, but in production code function calls may be nested in an order and depth which are hard to predict, or even impossible if they depend on user input.

I am not aware if there is any portable way, but the platform specific way would be to put an object on the stack and measure the difference between its address and the end of the stack, this will give you at runtime the stack space you have left.

At any rate, if your intention is to put a big object on the stack, you don't really gain much from not using heap memory allocation, the penalty from the memory allocation will be negligible, and afterwards, accessing data from it will be as fast as if it was on the stack, at the added benefit it will not depend on the limited stack size.

The purpose of the stack is not to store a program's bulk data, it is to keep track of the program's core structure so it can run. Do not put bulk data on the stack ever. Due to that intent, the stack size is almost always not more than a few megabytes, even for applications which are intended to use gigabytes of ram memory.